# Random color for animate in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to add the text effect using jquery with ui `animate`. Is there is a way to show all possible color randomly without defined all colors. For example color combination is based on `RGB`. 
Using the animate with color like

```
setInterval(function() {
jQuery(".font-style").animate({color: "red"}, 2000).
          animate({color: "green"}, 2000).animate({color: "blue"}, 2000);}, 400);
```

Is there is any possibilities to show the color combination of `RGB` Randomly in jquery. Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use a hex number

Comment: check my answer shortest code with demo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can generate a random color like this:

```
var newColor = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
jQuery(".font-style").animate({color: newColor}, 2000); // animate
```

This will create a random hex color such as #ff00cc.

**Note:** regular jQuery doesn't animate colors, you'll have to use [jQuery color plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var col = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
```

And than put `col` in your animate:

```
jQuery(".font-style").animate({color: col}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var hue = 'rgb('
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
```

Then add this `hue` in your color

```
jQuery(".font-style").animate({color: hue}, 2000).
          animate({color: hue}, 2000).animate({color: hue}, 2000);}, 400);
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/YD7Sb/324/) for **RANDOM** color for label

Comment: Modified your fiddle to include the setInterval http://jsfiddle.net/sonic1981/YD7Sb/329/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Math.random`

```
setInterval(function() {

var red= Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);
var blue = Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);
var green = Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);
jQuery(".font-style").animate({color: "red"}, red).
          animate({color: "green"}, green).animate({color: "blue"}, blue);}, 400);
```

if your running this continously though it'll probably become **unresponsive** pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_random_color() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Shortest code

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/pLgTY/)

```
"#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascripts random method, set boundaries and have it produce either hex or rgb codes. Assign them to variables and use those in place of "red", "green", "blue" etc.